# Bootstrap 5 how to set breakpoints on rows

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5, adaptive-layout

need make adaptation for the diagram in the screenshot below using **Bootstrap 5 for mobile screens**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I know it made like this

```
<table class="table table-borderless">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">C1</td>
    <td>C2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>C2</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: That's not related. OP is asking Bootstrap 5. You should probably use `row` and `col-*` classes

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).